# Datagrid inside Datagrid row template not updating when i update the observable array WPF

Tags: wpf, datagridview, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have bind the list of values in a `DataGrid`.
Added datagrid row template. When the row selected i am showing that template.Inside template i have a `DataGrid` with different list(`ObservableCollection`). `Array` has value but not updating in `DataGrid`.

My code:

**xaml**

```
  <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatient}"  SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding
                   MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                   Command="{Binding SingleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrd, Path=SelectedPatient}" />
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding Salutation}"  Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"  Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}"  Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender}"  Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"  Width="*"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">

                        <Grid Margin="30,10,30,0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,50">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding PatientVisits}">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Visit Date" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Complaint}"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Medication" Width="Auto"   Binding="{Binding Medication}"/>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                </DataGrid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid
```

**Cs code**
I have added the following code on row selection

```
   public void GetVisitHistoryForSelectedPatient()
        {
            PatientVisits = new ObservableCollection<StudyVisitModel>
            {
               new StudyVisitModel{VisitDate=DateTime.Now,Medication="Tablets and tonics"},
               new StudyVisitModel{VisitDate=DateTime.Now,Medication="Tablets and tonics"}
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("PatientVisits");
        }
```

Comment: Apply `Mode=TwoWay` to inner `DatagGrid` .

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in Visaul Studio output window?

Comment: I checked now by adding Mode=TwoWay. not working

Comment: no binding error, i can see only grid column headers @sthotakura

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in SingleClickCommand and see if that's getting hit?

Comment: yes @sthotakura . Its hitting and value is updated in that observable collection array. But not updating in grid. If i put AutoGenerateColumns="False" am not seeing anything(Small empty row showing) .  If i put AutoGenerateColumns="True"  i can see only the headers which i gave.

Comment: Is PatientVisits a property on Patient object?

Comment: no @sthotakura. Patients is separate list and PatientVisits is seperate list. When i click on row only am loading PatientVisits

Comment: Loading is fine. So these two lists are members of a same view model or patientvisits list a member of patient?

Comment: @sthotakura Both list are in same view model. also both are different list. Parentlist is not a member of parent object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125037/discussion-between-sthotakura-and-bala-g).